# recycle temp table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code.

```
If OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempTable', 'U') is not null
drop table #tempTable;

select 'bacon' into #tempTable
select * from #tempTable

If OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempTable', 'U') is not null
drop table #tempTable;

select 'sandwich' into #tempTable
select * from #tempTable
```

1. drop the temp table if it exists
2. create / populate it with a select into statement
3. drop the temp table if it exists
4. create / populate it with a select into statement

This is how I read the code I have written, but I think SSMS is reading it differently because I get error message:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 There is already an object named
>   '#tempTable' in the database.

I feel that maybe the If Object_ID parts might be getting hoisted to the top of code, or something with order of execution. The table doesn't get dropped at the 2nd drop table statement. I can of course use different temp tables as a work around, but I want to understand why this example doesn't work.

Comment: Add the keyword `GO` after each statement or at least after the second `DROP TABLE`

Comment: @bjones exactly what I needed. Write it as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that it thinks the temp table is still there as part of the batch.

```
If OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempTable', 'U') is not null
drop table #tempTable;

select 'bacon' into #tempTable
select * from #tempTable

If OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempTable', 'U') is not null
drop table #tempTable;

GO --At least this should do the trick

select 'sandwich' into #tempTable
select * from #tempTable
```

Although Microsoft suggests ["DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE should not be executed on the same table in the same batch. Otherwise an unexpected error may occur."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790.aspx)

Also note, if you are using this in a stored procedure with variables, after `GO` the variables will no longer be there.